# ACF Pro simple Business Directory - Requesting assistance with created Templates and associated Functions.php Coding

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, child-theme

I want to replicate the basic Business Directory functionality found at this URL. We've not had any luck with off-the-shelf software and our needs are very basic.

**https://onetopanga.com/directory**

This is passive content, there is no user engagement, no user postings, no user editing, no rating, no favoriting. Admin will manually add and edit listing as needed from the WP Dashboard.

The current directory is built in Joomla using SOBI Pro.

I have built something similar in the past, however this use case is different. What I built previously uses a different template .PHP file and URL Endpoint for each Category. More info on this is at this URL.

"https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/302769/how-do-i-control-what-template-is-shown-based-upon-taxonomy-term"

Unlike my previous use case, I want this setup to use one global template .PHP file usable by each Taxonomy Category.

The new website is built using X Theme and I already have the empty template files ready to be named and populated with ACF data.

I am crafty with HTML/CSS. I am not so crafty with what Templates to create, Functions.php coding, or PHP coding in general.

If you’re open to a little hand holding, here is what I am trying to accomplish.

**/directory**

This loads a template showing all categories in the same layout as we have at https://onetopanga.com/directory. Parent Category with a list of Child Categories below it.

**/directory/category-name**

This loads a category and shows a list of items in that that category. I want one global category template and it only needs to display the listing title. I can modify it from here.

**/directory/category-name/listing-name**

This loads a template displaying the listing and all data fields.

- What Taxonomy and Post Type Titles am I using.
- What template files do I need to create?
- What Functions.php code do I need to ensure the /directory
  /directory/category-name/ /directory/category-name/listing-name
  endpoints work and .PHP template files work?

Thanks for any and all help!